# RxSwift Chaining requests

Tags: swift, networking, observable, rx-swift, chaining

The problem I faced with is chaining 2 requests and handling errors.
Below an example of my code:

```
func fbLogin() -> Observable<String> { ... }

func userLogin(request: Request) -> Observable<User> { ... }

let signedWithLogin = loginTaps
    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: ())
    .flatMapLatest { _ in
        return fbLogin()
        .map({ ReqestState<String>.loaded($0) })
        .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { error  in
            return Driver.just(.error(error))
        })
        .startWith(.loading)
     }
     .map({ UserEndpoint.socialLogin(token: $0) })
     .flatMapLatest { request in
         return userLogin(request: request)
         .map({ ReqestState<User>.loaded($0) })
         .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { error  in
              return Driver.just(.error(error))
         })
         .startWith(.loading)
     }

signedWithLogin
    .drive(onNext: { response in
        print(response)
     })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Problem is when I cancel the facebook login popup I send `observer.onError(FBLoginManagerError.canceled)` error. This error catch first .`asDriver(onErrorRecover: { error` method but does't pass to the `.drive(onNext: { response`method.

How can I catch all errors in `.asDriver(onErrorRecover: { error` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mukesh is correct that you probably should avoid `Driver` until the end. Also, there's little point of having both `RequestState` types when you only really care about the final one (`RequestState<User>`)

Here's a simpler version that I think will do what you want:

```
let signedWithLogin = loginTaps
    .flatMapLatest {
        fbLogin()
            .map { UserEndpoint.socialLogin(token: $0) }
            .flatMap { userLogin(request: $0) }
            .map { RequestState.loaded($0) }
            .catchError { .just(.error($0)) }
            .startWith(.loading)
    }
    .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { fatalError($0.localizedDescription) }) // I'm using `fatalError()` here because if the above emits an error something has gone horribly wrong (like the RxSwift library isn't working anymore.)

signedWithLogin
    .drive(onNext: { response in
        print(response)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The above assumes you change your `UserEndpoint.socialLogin(token:)` function to accept a String instead of a `RequestState<String>`.

It also assumes that `fbLogin()` and `userLogin(request:)` only emit one value each. You might want to consider switching them to `Single`s.

Comment: This solution really useful. Thank you!